# How to hide an element within modal fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I want to hide "Enter Password" first and then show when I click the radio private. But my code for this action does not work. I write the javascript within head to hide the text first and then show the text. But my code does not work. How can I fix the code? Thank you so much!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#pwd").hide();
       $("#inlineRadio2").click(function(){
          $("#pwd").show(500);
       });
     });

  </script>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="container">
 <h2>Modal Example</h2>
 <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

 <!-- Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

 <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
         <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
       </div>

       <div class="modal-body">
         <form id="form_room" method="post" action="/create-room">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="room_name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="room_name" name="room_name" placeholder="Room Name" />
            </div>
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <label class="form-check-inline">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="room_type" id="inlineRadio1" value="public"> Public
                </label>

                <label class="form-check-inline">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="room_type" id="inlineRadio2" value="private"> Private
                </label>

                <label class="form-check-inline">
                  <p id="pwd">Enter password</p>
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="text" name="text" id="pwd" value="private">
                </label>

            </fieldset>

      </div>

       <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
       </div>
    </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have test this code, it is working as you are saying, let me know what is exactly not happening from you want?

Comment: @Jigar7521 Hi Jigar7521, I am sorry for my mistake before, the code I posted first works, but the new code does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#pwd").hide();
       $("#inlineRadio2").click(function(){
          $("#pwd").show(500);
       });
     });

  </script>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="container">
 <h2>Modal Example</h2>
 <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

 <!-- Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

 <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
         <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
       </div>

       <div class="modal-body">
         <form id="form_room" method="post" action="/create-room">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="room_name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="room_name" name="room_name" placeholder="Room Name" />
            </div>
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <label class="form-check-inline">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="room_type" id="inlineRadio1" value="public"> Public
                </label>

                <label class="form-check-inline">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="room_type" id="inlineRadio2" value="private"> Private
                </label>

                <label class="form-check-inline">
                  <p id="pwd">Enter password</p>
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="text" name="text" id="pwd" value="private">
                </label>

            </fieldset>

      </div>

       <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
       </div>
    </div>

 </div>
</div>
```